# how to configure nodejs to accept all request from outside of localhost?

Tags: javascript, node.js, next.js

I developed an application with NextJs then built it. I run it on node server using
'npm run start' at Powershell. it works fine on localhost on port 80, but my server does not accept any request from outside neither by domain name or IP address. how should I configure application or nodejs to accept all request ?
OS is windows server 2019

Comment: do not run on port 80. You need to configure CORS. Lots of online blogs for this. Does this help? [https://www.section.io/engineering-education/how-to-use-cors-in-nodejs-with-express/]

Comment: Provide more info. Code where you start your listener. How this is deployed (on your own, heroku, aws, etc.), are you using docker,etc. . There are many possible reasons why a site wouldn’t be reachable.

Comment: Try listening on '0.0.0.0'

Comment: my server is windows server 2019 and I installed Nodejs on it. then deploy Nextjs by  'npm run start' at Powershell

Comment: my nextjs app does not have custom server.js file

Answer (score 0):

You need to allow **CORS**

```
res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*');
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to this `cors` npm module - https://www.npmjs.com/package/cors

```
var cors = require('cors');

var app = express();
app.use(cors());
```

It provides many features to configure cors setting including domain whitelisting, enabling cors for specific apis and many more.